# How to mark the final shortest path in A Star algorithm?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, shortest-path, path-finding, a-star

My code actually works, **but i don't know how to mark the final shortest path when the code reaches the end node**, can anyone help me?
[my a-star algorithm image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cdpY.png)

The code below contains the main methods to implementation, the rest is just for manipulation and editing path finder window configuration in runtime

```java
private void startPath() {
    ArrayList<Node> neighbors = getNeighbors(curNode);
    curNode.setBackground(Color.orange);
    closedNodes.add(curNode);
    openNodes.remove(curNode);

    for (Node nb : neighbors) {
        calculateCosts(nb);
        if (!openNodes.contains(nb)) {
            openNodes.add(nb);
        }
    }
    curNode = smallestFCostNode();
    curNode.setBackground(Color.red);
    startNode.setBackground(Color.blue);
}

private ArrayList<Node> findDiagonal(Node node) {
    int[][] cornerNodes = {{node.x + 1, node.y - 1}, {node.x - 1, node.y + 1}, {node.x + 1, node.y + 1}, {node.x - 1, node.y - 1}};
    int[][] possibleDiagonal = {{node.x, node.y - 1}, {node.x - 1, node.y}, {node.x + 1, node.y}, {node.x, node.y - 1}};
    int[][] possibleDiagonalV = {{node.x + 1, node.y}, {node.x, node.y + 1}, {node.x, node.y + 1}, {node.x - 1, node.y}};
    ArrayList<Node> denyNodes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        Node dNode = nodes[possibleDiagonal[i][0]][possibleDiagonal[i][1]];
        Node dNodeV = nodes[possibleDiagonalV[i][0]][possibleDiagonalV[i][1]];
        if (dNode.nodeType == 2 && dNodeV.nodeType == 2) {
            dNode.setBackground(Color.pink);
            dNodeV.setBackground(Color.pink);
            denyNodes.add(nodes[cornerNodes[i][0]][cornerNodes[i][1]]);
        }
    }
    return denyNodes;
}

private Node smallestFCostNode() {
    ArrayList<Double> onFCostList = new ArrayList<>();
    openNodes.forEach(on -> {
        onFCostList.add(on.fCost);
    });
    double onFCost = Collections.min(onFCostList);
    ArrayList<Integer> nodesIndex = containsTwice(onFCostList, onFCost);
    if (nodesIndex.size() > 1) {
        ArrayList<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<>();
        nodesIndex.forEach((i) -> {
            nodeList.add(openNodes.get(i));
        });
        return smallestHCostNode(nodeList);
    }
    int index = onFCostList.indexOf(onFCost);
    return openNodes.get(index);
}

private Node smallestHCostNode(ArrayList<Node> nodes) {
    ArrayList<Double> hCostList = new ArrayList<>();
    nodes.forEach((n) -> {
        hCostList.add(n.hCost);
    });
    int index = hCostList.indexOf(Collections.min(hCostList));
    return nodes.get(index);
}

private ArrayList<Integer> containsTwice(ArrayList<Double> list, Object value) {
    ArrayList<Integer> nodesIndex = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).equals(value)) {
            nodesIndex.add(i);
        }
    }
    return nodesIndex;
}

private ArrayList<Node> getNeighbors(Node node) {
    ArrayList<Node> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
    int x = node.x;
    int y = node.y;
    int[][] neightborsPos = {{x + 1, y}, {x + 1, y + 1}, {x, y + 1}, {x - 1, y + 1}, {x - 1, y}, {x - 1, y - 1}, {x, y - 1}, {x + 1, y - 1}};
    for (int i = 0; i < neightborsPos.length; i++) {
        Node curNeighbor = nodes[neightborsPos[i][0]][neightborsPos[i][1]];
        if (curNeighbor.nodeType != 2 && !closedNodes.contains(curNeighbor)) {
            neighbors.add(curNeighbor);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Node> denyNodes = findDiagonal(node);
    if (denyNodes.size() > 0) {
        denyNodes.forEach(n -> {
            neighbors.remove(n);
        });
    }
    neighbors.forEach(e -> e.setBackground(Color.yellow));
    return neighbors;
}

private void calculateCosts(Node node) {
    int xf = finalNode.x - node.x;
    int yf = finalNode.y - node.y;
    int xs = startNode.x - node.x;
    int ys = startNode.y - node.y;
    double h = format(Math.hypot(xf, yf));
    double g = format(Math.hypot(xs, ys));
    double f = format(h + g);
    node.setCosts(h, g, f);
}
```

Comment: There many ways to mark the path: have a field in `Node` to indicate that it is part of the path, or better have a reference to the Node's parent. Alternatively collect all path nodes in a collection. For more help post [mre].

Comment: I implemented a property to get the parents of each node, like you said, i've thougth doing by this way other times, but I didn't consider that each node is updated at once, and was thinking about the current progress, not to get the reverse path (getting it by end), but thanks for answering!

Comment: When you add a Node to the queue you can update its (single) parent.